# Microsoft.Graph.AttendeeType not enumerated correctly

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am attempting to create an event through the Microsoft Graph API inviting users as attendees. The code to set the attendees is as follows:

```
var attendees = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Attendee>();
        foreach (var e in emailAddresses)
        {
            var userProfile = await AzureGraph.GetOtherUserProfile(e);
            if (e != currentUserEmail.First())
            {
                Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress email = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress();
                email.Name = userProfile.DisplayName;
                email.Address = e;
                attendees.Add(new Microsoft.Graph.Attendee()
                {
                    EmailAddress = email,
                    Type = Microsoft.Graph.AttendeeType.Optional
                });
            }
        }

await AzureGraph.AddEvent(new Microsoft.Graph.Event
        {
            Subject = string.Format("Follow Up: {0}", Id),
            Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody
            {
                Content = "content"
            },
            Start = start,
            End = start.AddMinutes(30),
            Attendees = attendees
        });
```

However, when making the request, i get a Bad Request response. The reason for this is that the 'Type' of an attendee is a n enum of Microsoft.Graph.AttendeeType and this is not being enumerated properly. Therefore it is attempting to send through the numeric value '1' instead of the string value "Optional" causing it to fail.

I was able to confirm this using fiddler, if i manually change the numeric value to the string value then it works no problem.

Has anybody come across this or have any ideas how i can solve this?

Many Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now managed to solve this. The solution is a bit of a hack but it works. My original call code was as follows:

```
public static async Task AddEvent(Event e)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _calendarUrl))
    {
        var token = await GetToken();
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
        req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var requestContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Subject = e.Subject,
            Body = new
            {
                ContentType = "HTML",
                Content = e.Body.Content
            },
            Start = new
            {
                DateTime = e.Start,
                TimeZone = "UTC"
            },
            End = new
            {
                DateTime = e.End,
                TimeZone = "UTC"
            }
        });
        req.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException("Event could not be added to calendar");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have now changed this to:

```
    public static async Task AddEvent(Event e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _calendarUrl))
            {
                var token = await GetToken();
                req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
                req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

                IList<Attendee> attendees = new List<Attendee>();

                foreach(var a in e.Attendees)
                {
                    attendees.Add(new Attendee()
                    {
                        EmailAddress = a.EmailAddress,
                        Type = Enum.GetName(typeof(AttendeeType), AttendeeType.Optional)
                    });
                }

                var requestContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    Subject = e.Subject,
                    Body = new
                    {
                        ContentType = "HTML",
                        Content = e.Body.Content
                    },
                    Start = new
                    {
                        DateTime = e.Start,
                        TimeZone = "UTC"
                    },
                    End = new
                    {
                        DateTime = e.End,
                        TimeZone = "UTC"
                    },
                    Attendees = attendees
                });
                req.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new HttpRequestException("Event could not be added to calendar");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As well as adding the following local class:

```
    private class Attendee
    {
        public EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Essentially, the Graph Attendee expected: 
   1. an EmailAddress object containing Name (string) and Email (string). 
   2. a Type object of type AttendeeType which was the enum not being passed correctly.

Therefore, i created my own version of the class Attendee to contain the same EmailAddress object and Type of type string as the API expects it to be.

I then had to change the enum type to the name of the enum rather than the int value. This was done as follows:

```
attendees.Add(new Attendee()
{
    EmailAddress = a.EmailAddress,
    Type = Enum.GetName(typeof(AttendeeType), AttendeeType.Optional)
});
```

This gave me the value "Optional" rather than 1 which made it acceptable to the API.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

It looks like a major oversight on microsoft's part to use an enum in the code and the expect a string rather than an integer in the API and i think this needs addressing.